# Event click on ListView (extends ListActivity)

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

i have this code but i can't see the action when i click on a item from the list.
This code shows me the info on ArrayList profilesArrayList but i dont know how i check what item i am selecting form the listview. Anyone can help me?

```
profilesArrayList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    profilesArrayList = copyProfilesToArrayList();
    ProfileAdapter adapter = new ProfileAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.profiles_item, profilesArrayList);

    listViewProfiles = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listViewProfiles.setAdapter(adapter);

    listViewProfiles.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            switch(position) {
            case 0:

                Log.d("cardNumber", profilesArrayList.get(0).getCardNumber());

                break;
```

Comment: Your switch statement means that you will only log when the first item in the list is clicked. Is this really what you want?

Comment: yes, is it what i want. for differents items i have differents actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your container class for this code is the ListActivity, just override the onListItemClick for that class, rather than set it as an OnItemClickListener for the view.  That works for me

```
public class ProfileList extends ListActivity
{
    private ArrayList<Profile> profilesArrayList;
    @Override 
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //populate your arraylist

        setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<Profile>() );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Log.d("cardNumber", profilesArrayList.get(position).getCardNumber());
    }
}
```

Comment: i had try this method but dont work. i dont know whay i can make actions where i click on list view :(

Comment: I think we may all be a little unclear on what it is that isn't working for you.  Once you're in the onListItemClick function, the `position` parameter is the index into your array that was clicked.  So in your example, to get the `Profile` object that was clicked do `profilesArrayList.get(position);`

Comment: i cant understand what i am making wrong. when i run in the emulator and click on a item, item dont say selected. i have to move the keys of emulator to select a item but still whithout working.

Comment: The item doesnt light up like it is selected?

Comment: i am trying to print messages to debug but still without working. the listview it's working, i see my data on the listview

Comment: Like fleetway76 said in his comment, your onListItemClick function is only going to print right now if you select the first item, try getting rid of the switch and changing your log to `Log.d("cardNumber", profilesArrayList.get(position).getCardNumber());`

Comment: And don't forget to call `super.onListItemClick()` that is likely why your items arent lighting up

Comment: @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), profilesArrayList.get(position).getCardNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

Comment: Looks about right, I'm not too familiar with how Toast works, but thats the general idea right there

Comment: i will try to make listview whith extends Activity, i am tired of try a lot of differents things

Comment: I added some sample code, it is incomplete, but hopefully it gives you a good idea of where you should be headed with your code

Comment: i still with the same problem, i make the listview in different way. can you say me your mail for we speak better? thanks

Comment: I would like to help you, I just don't want to post my email on here, if you want to give me yours I can try to help some more this evening

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getSelectedItemPosition() and add INVALID_POSITION as one of your possible cases